# OpenSSL rsa_private_decrypt error:0406506c:lib(4):func(101):reason(108)

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to decrypt with private key with function RSA_private_decrypt in openssl. The demo test program is finished, but unfortunately it doesn't work. All the codes were modified from original test module in openssl.

I've checked the key and ciphertext, all is OK.
After compiled, I got an error when tried to run the program:
error:0406506C:lib(4):func(101):reason(108)
What does it mean? How to find the reason? Any one could help me?
Thanks for all!

```
/* test vectors from p1ovect1.txt */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "e_os.h"

#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#ifdef OPENSSL_NO_RSA
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("No RSA support\n");
    return(0);
}
#else
#include <openssl/rsa.h>

#define SetKey \
  BN_dec2bn(&key->n, n); \
  BN_dec2bn(&key->d, d); \
  BN_dec2bn(&key->e, e); \
  return 0;

int get_key(RSA *key)
{
    static unsigned char n[] =
"9371630458513538614700745634649520797491568155168133301060614397"
"9751660657428852845087672310448592787191681231125442581642251207"
"6274432436386486727760163436686441566403892007588636246674079539"
"8424907957591099362409156898826262775257410650392782996749570788"
"0595781666554070793222145163225943407723575126201759";

    static unsigned char e[] = "65537";

    static unsigned char d[] =
"1898149483594133261692443925634950319146483294806014944814053061"
"9149847316274937709472416531865886761023275045576683779067080313"
"8692140564270476598322907775584173165745869684564814756756282410"
"5523409115330652968833389931424803742277184063260858317510246331"
"1992939017567767983973542782514344223016146752560753";

    static unsigned char p[] =
"1898149483594133261692443925634950319146483294806014944814053061"
"9149847316274937709472416531865886761023275045576683779067080313"
"8692140564270476598322907775584173165745869684564814756756282410"
"5523409115330652968833389931424803742277184063260858317510246331"
"1992939017567767983973542782514344223016146752560753";

    static unsigned char q[] =
"\x00\xC9\x7F\xB1\xF0\x27\xF4\x53\xF6\x34\x12\x33\xEA\xAA\xD1\xD9"
"\x35\x3F\x6C\x42\xD0\x88\x66\xB1\xD0\x5A\x0F\x20\x35\x02\x8B\x9D"
"\x89";

    static unsigned char dmp1[] =
"\x59\x0B\x95\x72\xA2\xC2\xA9\xC4\x06\x05\x9D\xC2\xAB\x2F\x1D\xAF"
"\xEB\x7E\x8B\x4F\x10\xA7\x54\x9E\x8E\xED\xF5\xB4\xFC\xE0\x9E\x05";

    static unsigned char dmq1[] =
"\x00\x8E\x3C\x05\x21\xFE\x15\xE0\xEA\x06\xA3\x6F\xF0\xF1\x0C\x99"
"\x52\xC3\x5B\x7A\x75\x14\xFD\x32\x38\xB8\x0A\xAD\x52\x98\x62\x8D"
"\x51";

    static unsigned char iqmp[] =
"\x36\x3F\xF7\x18\x9D\xA8\xE9\x0B\x1D\x34\x1F\x71\xD0\x9B\x76\xA8"
"\xA9\x43\xE1\x1D\x10\xB2\x4D\x24\x9F\x2D\xEA\xFE\xF8\x0C\x18\x26";

  BN_dec2bn(&key->n, n);
  BN_dec2bn(&key->d, d);
  BN_dec2bn(&key->e, e);
  return 0;
}

static int pad_unknown(void)
{
    unsigned long l;
    while ((l = ERR_get_error()) != 0)
      if (ERR_GET_REASON(l) == RSA_R_UNKNOWN_PADDING_TYPE)
    return(1);
    return(0);
}

static const char rnd_seed[] = "string to make the random number generator think it has entropy";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    int err=0;
    int v;
    RSA *key;
    unsigned char ptext[256];
    unsigned char err_msg[256];
    static unsigned char ptext_ex[] = "\x54\x85\x9b\x34\x2c\x49\xea\x2a";
    unsigned char ctext_ex[]=
    "11A10DBC32E75CD4A4A5FBDF79B9DCEB5FAA8CCA56925F8FFD09265CAE63"
    "02F4FAD8CF647D2C64107EEE254033B81DD22DACAE7ECBE873CD958D248C"
    "5F60CD223D5C963077406E398232CF4C36715FD63F640F1AF1E44E86D244"
    "6FB6B773A17B790938FAC5DFE9257639D60FB1FA4B2082098068549D37C6"
    "EBD5164E77A68876";
    int plen;
    int clen = 0;
    int num;
    int n;

    CRYPTO_malloc_debug_init();
    CRYPTO_dbg_set_options(V_CRYPTO_MDEBUG_ALL);
    CRYPTO_mem_ctrl(CRYPTO_MEM_CHECK_ON);

    RAND_seed(rnd_seed, sizeof rnd_seed); /* or OAEP may fail */

    plen = sizeof(ptext_ex) - 1;


    key = RSA_new();
    clen = get_key(key);
    printf("clen[%d]\n", clen);
    key->flags |= RSA_FLAG_NO_CONSTTIME;

    key->p=NULL;
    key->q=NULL;
    key->dmp1=NULL;
    key->dmq1=NULL;
    key->iqmp=NULL;
    printf("n[%s]\n", BN_bn2dec(key->n));
    num = strlen(ctext_ex);
    printf("num[%d]\n", num);
    memset(ptext, '\0', sizeof(ptext));
    num = RSA_private_decrypt(num, ctext_ex, ptext, key,
                  RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
    ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err_msg);
    printf("num[%d], err[%s]\n", num, err_msg);
    for(v=0; v<6; v++) {
        printf("ptext%d[%d]\n", v, ptext[v]);
    }
    RSA_free(key);

    CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
    ERR_remove_thread_state(NULL);

    CRYPTO_mem_leaks_fp(stderr);

#ifdef OPENSSL_SYS_NETWARE
    if (err) printf("ERROR: %d\n", err);
#endif
    return err;
    }
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Err...
I found the reason finally.
The ciphered text need to be convert to HEX first.
After I did that, it worked well.
It's really a stupid question.

Comment: Any idea how to decipher the error message? I'm running into a similar issue.

Comment: @leecbaker Use `openssl errstr 0406506C` this will print `error:0406506C:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:data greater than mod len`