# RSA Decryption in C++, Encryption in PHP

Tags: php, c++, encryption, openssl, rsa

I am working on an application which generates RSA encrypted session keys and stores them in a database. Later theses keys are transfered to a C++ application via Javascript. Therefore I want to use the OpenSSL library. I generated a 2048 bit key pair with openssl, which is used in both methods.

My PHP functions works like this:

```
function encrypt_with_public_key($input, $key)
{   
    openssl_public_encrypt($input, $crypttext, $key, OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING); 
    return $crypttext;          
}
```

and

```
$fp = fopen("public.pem","r");
$public_pem = fread($fp,8192);
fclose($fp);

$public_key = openssl_get_publickey($public_pem);

$sessionKey = ...;
$encSessionKey = encrypt_with_public_key($sessionKey, $public_key);
```

I tested this part successfully. The part I have trouble with, is the C++ part. I use MS Visual Studio 2013. **Edit**: added hex encoding (using Crypto++)

```
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
...
string decrypted, encoded;
decrypted.clear();

char privateKey[] =
    "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"\
    ...

RSA *rsa = NULL;
BIO *keybio;
keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf(privateKey, strlen(privateKey));

rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keybio, &rsa, NULL, NULL);

StringSource ss2(input, true,
    new HexEncoder(
        new StringSink(encoded)
    )
);

RSA_private_decrypt(encoded.length(), (unsigned char *)encoded.data(), (unsigned char *)decrypted.data(), rsa, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);

FBLOG_INFO("", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));

return decrypted;
```

Note that the private key is not read from a file.

OpenSSL returns the following error: 0406506C: lib(4): func(101): reason(108).

It means afaik that my input data is longer than the modulus length (please correct me if I'm wrong). Anyone who knows how to handle this? I thought such problems are solved through the padding parameters.

The input data is the direct output of the php encrypt function (no base64 oder anything).

Comment: Just bike shedding... this is known as key transport: `$encSessionKey = encrypt_with_public_key($sessionKey, $public_key);`. You might want to use Diffie-Hellman, which is a key agreement scheme. Sign the temporary DH keys with the RSA key, and it offers MitM protection and forward secrecy. (And TLS 1.3 is deprecating RSA key transport in favor of forward secrecy key agreement schemes).

Comment: Could still be the input data. Could you try and create a signature (over any data) using the private key instead in your C(++) code?

Comment: See also [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12191045/589259). That looks like a ciphertext issue as well.

Comment: After reading the Q/A I added Hex encoding of the input data, but it didn't change anything.
@jww: i know about Diffie-Hellman and its a good point, but the structure of the application makes my solution more usable.
I will try the signature next.

Comment: did you solved the issue, I m facing a similar issue between node.js & c++ ?